# Multiple if-statements in a lambda expression

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am encoding categorical variables in my dataframe. I found a nice pythonic way to do this with lambda expressions. For instance, the following line of code replaces the gender categories "male" and "female" (encoded as strings) with values 0 and 1.

```
train_frame['Sex'] = train_frame['Sex'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x =='male' else 0)
```

Now my question is, can i also do this but then for more than two categories? (So more then 1 if in the expression so to say).

I am trying to do this for the place where people Embarked on a ship, where I want to represent the place where people boarded the ship with an integer (Some background info: S = Southampton, C = Cherbourg, Q = Queenstown)

I tried to do something like this, but it does not work:

```
#Southampton = 0, Cherbourg = 1, Queenstown = 2
train_frame['Embarked'] = train_frame['Embarked'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x =='S', 1 if x=='C' else 2 )
```

**Can somebody explain me if it is possible to use lambda-expressions with multiple if-statements?** and, slightly off-topic: is there a more pythonic way to encode categoricals in a dataframe?

Comment: `lambda` uses an expression, not statements. [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) can be chained, though.

Comment: I do not agree with the duplicate as I am specifically asking about multiple if-statements in lambda-expressions, and the question that my question should be a duplicate from is totally different (It is about adding columns to a dataframe, something I am not doing).

Comment: @Psychotechnopath nromashchenko already answered that aspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/59372653/1011724 so is it still necessary to reopen?

Comment: @Dan As the question is not a duplicate IMO, yes, it should be re-opened.

Comment: If the question is really about chaining multiple if statements, then you shouldn't have included all the extra parts about categorical variables or mentioned pandas. The fact that you did makes it seem like the real question is how to encode categoricals in pandas. Either way, it's not really a duplicate since you should be doing OHE anyway.

Comment: Yes but as I'm not that experienced I decided to include more context as I wasn't sure if the problem was using the apply function or the chaining of the multiple if-statements in the expression. Anyways, my question is answered and I learned some new stuff so thank you very much =).

Comment: @Psychotechnopath - reopened, I have no problem with it.

Comment: @jezrael tyvm =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
   lambda x: 0 if x== 'S' else 1 if x == 'C' else 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a `dict`

**Ex:**

```
data = {'S': 0, 'C': 1}
train_frame['Embarked_N'] = train_frame['Embarked'].map(data).fillna(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `.apply` is generally not a good idea if you can avoid it. In this case, I would suggest rather using [`.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) or [scikit-learn's transformers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). as you probably want to encode these into multiple columns. Alternatively, you can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
train_frame['Sex'] = train_frame['Sex'].replace({
    "S": 0,
    "C": 1,
    "X": 2,
})
```

you could use a `defaultdict` if you really want that `else`. But I recommend rather going with get_dummies or sklearn (note if you want to keep them all in one column for some reason, sklearn has label_binarizer).

Comment: A `defaultdict` will create new entries when encountering unknown keys. The default argument of [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) might be better.

Comment: @YannVernier how would you set that default in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't really used pandas; perhaps its paired list of `to_replace` and `value` combined with a match-anything regex? Making a defaultdict-like subclass with `get`-like behaviour instead of `setdefault`-like is also an option.

Comment: Can you explain why using .apply isn't a good idea? And why would I want to encode them into multiple columns? I simply want to use the categorical feature to train my SVM on.

Comment: Regarding `apply` - it's not efficient, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/1011724). Regarding the treatment of categoricals, read up on [one hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f), or categorical encoding in general. It's too long a topic for a comment, but in short your method is imposing an artificial ordering of your categories i.e. 0 < 1 < 2.